# Simulation of signal modulation in Vivado VHDL

Tags: vhdl, signal, vivado, bpsk

I am trying to simulate a BPSK modulation in VHDL.

I did a simulation in MAtlab and after that rewrote it to VHDL by using MATLAB tool.

```
architecture rtl of test is
signal inphase : in signed(1 downto 0);
signal qphase  : in signed(1 downto 0);
begin
...............

end rtl;
```

**EDIT 1: I have fixed the problem below.**
I run this code in Vivado. It could be compiled because of the following errors:

- Error:  is not a signal
- Error:  is not a signal

I have simulated other processes using 'signal', they worked...but in this case it doesnt work.

**EDIT 2:**

Could someone explain to me what 2#01#,2 in ´to_signed(2#01#,2)` means?

Comment: there's a typo in `std.logic_vector(inphase);`

Comment: `2#01#` means it's `01` in `base 2`, so binary... and the second attribute of `to_signed` denotes the resulting size of the conversion into the `signed`.

Comment: @po.pe what is the result of to_signed(2#01#,2)? or to_signed(2#00#,2), to_signed(2#11#,2)

Comment: `to_signed(2#01#,2)` gives a `std_logic_vector` signed representation of size 2 that holds the value 1 and is actually the same as if you write `to_signed(1, 2)`

Comment: @po.pe `to_signed(2#00#,2)` is `to_signed(0, 2)`, isnt?  and `to_signed(2#11#,2)` is `to_signed(1, 2)`, ?

Comment: first one is correct, but the 2nd one would be `to_signed(3, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This an answer for your second question regard the base notation and signed conversion as the original problem seems to be resolved.

The number notation with the `#` represents a certain base.
`2#01#` is binary `01`, `16#0f#` is hex `0F` and `10#10#` would be normal decimal representation. But I would say this notation is rather unconventional and probably only used for non-standard bases.

The `to_signed(number, size)` converts a number into a `signed std_logic_vector` representation of given size. This means you can do something like

```
signal a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal b : signed(7 downto 0);

b <= to_signed(100, 8);
a <= std_logic_vector(b);
```

or directly

```
a <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(100, 8));
```

It's because your synthesizer doesn't automatically now how it should convert a number in terms of size.

Comment: can i express for example 5 using `to_signed`? if yes, how does this converion look?

Comment: i have seen an example: to signed(442,16) = 0,0135 amd am trying to understand how it was computed

Comment: the first one, storing 5 in a 8bit signed would look like `a <= to_signed(5, 8)` and regarding the second, this looks odd and not like VHDL.